# How to open a new page from a button in a Dialog Box?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I open a new page from a button in a Dialog Box?

This box is created using:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('File')
```

And this is the `File.html`:

```
function sabermais(){
  window.open('www.google.com')
}

<input type="button" class="action" value="Learn more" onclick="sabermais()" />
```

It works if the box is called with:

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('File')
```

But in this case, I can't use `scriplets`,and I need them.

This sounds a bit confusing but I guess someone can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, for some reason, using `createTemplateFromFile` won't work for you?  But `createHtmlOutputFromFile` will?  That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Not to me either... but the issue here is the SandboxMode. In my question, I have not mentioned I was using NATIVE. With IFRAME, it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use IFRAME mode:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('File')
  .evaluate()
  .setWidth(450)
  .setHeight(450)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

My first answer below:

And `<a>` tag in a dialog box will open a link in a new tab.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">button</a>
```

That's not a button, but you can use a link, and style it to look like a button.

```
<a style="border: 1px solid #990000;
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  " href="https://www.google.com">button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea, but I must use the sabermais() function